# TV Wire Concealer

Tags: wiring

I bought [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086CCHYL3) wire concealer with outlet off of Amazon that uses 6’ of romex wiring. I know Chicago has a big problem with romex, is something this short allowed or does anyone know if it’s a total Romex ban?

If this can’t be used, does anyone have experience mounting a similar box behind their TV with bx cable instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You slightly misunderstand. Cook County does not ban NM/NM-B wiring (common brand “Romex”) but it mandates the use of conduit to contain all power wiring. You could legally put NM cables in conduit, but you’d be insane to do so (it’s no fun to pull, and requires vastly over-sized conduits compared to individual wires).
2. That product doesn’t appear to be using NM cable. It’s probably stranded cordage. Still illegal to bury in your wall in Cook County, IL, though.
3. You should be OK DIY’ing the same thing with your own junction boxes and AC/MC/FMC assuming you keep the length under 25’ per https://www.chicago.gov/content/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/Building%20Code/CodeMemorandumElectricalWorkExBuildingRehab.pdf (published by Chicago specifically, may or may not apply to all of Cook County).

Answer (score -1):

It's not allowed to be used in Chicago. I would never install anything electrical from Amazon in my house. You can get an old work metal box and fish some BX cable from it to a nearby outlet and connect to it. You might have to drill through a stud or two or cut some drywall and notch the studs. Be sure to use the proper BX to box connectors.

Comment: I’d agree with the Amazon rule most of the time, but this is by EchoGear which is owned by LeGrand (multi-billion dollar international electronics company). Should be pretty safe, but to your point I might have to stick with bx

Comment: “They don't even sell Romex in Chicago, it's not allowed.” Cite? I’ve shopped at Menard’s in Cook County and they do sell NM/NM-B. True, you may not use it there but you can take it somewhere else. https://www.menards.com/main/electrical/electrical-wire-cable/indoor-electrical-cable/12-gauge-nm-b-cable-with-ground-wire/sku3691660/p-1474478926957-c-6441.htm (link is not store-specific, you’ll have to plug in a zip code like 60133).

Comment: @nobody  That might be fairly recent because I remember trying to get some for work in Indiana and couldn't get it anywhere. Home Depot was the one that said they couldn't even sell it.  Edited answer.

Comment: @nobody          But you could get it outside the city limits.